# simple installation problem in rosjava_core

Tags: ros, rosjava-core

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry I'm totally new to use ROS. I have had a java agent (program) which was used to control satellites and now I want to use it into ROS.
I have read some documents and think it should be okay for the running concept of the ROS. After that, I've passed all tutorials of ROS but when I try to install rosjava_core, I meet some problems. I don't know why I can't install it. When I follow the "rosws update", it just tell me:

---

[rosjava_core] Installing https://code.google.com/p/rosjava (default) to /home/wildfire/Robtic_java_workspace/rosjava_core
WARNING [vcstools] Command failed: 'hg --version'
errcode: 127:
/bin/sh: hg: not found
[/vcstools]
Exception caught during install: Error processing 'rosjava_core' : Unable to create vcs client of type hg for /home/wildfire/Robtic_java_workspace/rosjava_core: "Could not determine whether hg is installed 'hg --version returned 127, maybe hg is not installed'"

ERROR: Error processing 'rosjava_core' : Unable to create vcs client of type hg for /home/wildfire/Robtic_java_workspace/rosjava_core: "Could not determine whether hg is installed 'hg --version returned 127, maybe hg is not installed'"

---

Anyone can tell me what's this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36917/simple-installation-problem-in-rosjava_core/) by [wildfire](https://answers.ros.org/users/2576/wildfire/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2012-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Same answer as [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/35624/installation-problems-with-fuerte-and-rosjava/#35627)

---

Originally posted by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) with karma: 682 on 2012-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1